# Prove inequality using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I know this has something to with remainder theorem and taylor expansion but I can't figure out where we got the LHS and RHS from and the proper method behind it.

$$\frac{3x^2}{2} < \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2x+1}}-1+x+ \frac{5x^3}{2} < \frac{3x^2}{2}+ \frac{35x^4}{8}$$

Comment: Hint : $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+1}}=1-x+\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{5}{2}x^3+\frac{35}{8}x^4+O(x^5)$